# how to show delete button in right corner of Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have file input where after selecting image file a image preview is shown, Here is the jquery code

```
<script>
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

Html code->

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="cretor" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<img id="output" width="80" height="80">
```

The above codes generate image preview instantly after selecting an image but how can i show delete button in the top right corner of image and reset the file input and remove that image

here is what I've tried to show delete button at top right corner of image

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <button id="clear" onclick="twz()">x</a>
    <img src="blob:https://www.example.com/c880bfa4-25d0-4e2b-91e4-d722b864cc79" id="output">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-wrap {
    position: relative;

}
.img-wrap .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    z-index: 100;

}
```

Now how can i generate button and place it in the right corner because loadFile function only generate image preview

Comment: Quick observation... <button id="clear" onclick="twz()">x</a> has an anchor closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 mistakes in your code:

1- you didn't close correctly your `button` so the right markup should be:

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="cretor" accept="image/*"onchange="loadFile(event)">


<div class="img-wrap">
<button id="clear" class="hide" onclick="twz()">x</button>
<img id="output" width="80" height="80">
```

2- The second is that in your css you try to select a class named `close`, but the markup has a `id="clear"` so you can change your css in this way and it will work fine:

```
.img-wrap {
position: relative;
float:left;
}

 .img-wrap #clear {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
right: 2px;
z-index: 100;

}

 .hide{
  display:none;
 }
```

You can show the button only when the image is choosen removing the class `hide` from the button.  Your script becomes:

```
<script>
 var loadFile = function(event) {
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
$("#clear").removeClass("hide");
};
</script>
```

Comment: the problem I'm facing is that the preview is being generated dynamically so the delete button also should be generated dynamically

Comment: yes i'm using jquery, so i should generate buuton inside img-wrap div?

Comment: Yes you can add a button when the event is fired.
Or alternativly you can take hidden the button and show in the moment the image is loaded.

Comment: i tried var r= $('<button id="vty" onclick="twz()">x</button>');
        $(".img-wrap").append(r); but it is adding button again and again

Comment: I changed my answer.
My idea is show the botton only when the img is loaded, and keep hidden with a class "hide" before...